# ArcGIS Pro Floating Dockpane initial Width and Height as a proportion of screen resolution

Tags: c#, height, width, arcgis, dockpanel

Is there a way to set the initial width and height of a floating Dockpane in ArcGIS Pro as a proportion of the screen resolution?

I understand that the width or height is set in DAML via the width and height attributes.  ie:

```
<dockPane id="myDockpane"
 caption="My Dockpane"
 className="myDockpaneViewModel"
 dock="float"
 width="1200"
 height="700"
 <content className="myDockpaneView" />
</dockPane>
```

However, how can i make these values proportional to the screen resolution of the current user?  For example, if the users screen resolution was 1920 x 1080 and i wanted the initial floating dockpane to be 60% of this (i.e. 1152 x 648).

Can this be achieved via Bindings or Code-Behind?  I am unsure as to how this would work using ESRI's DAML (where the Dockpane width and height are set).